# Node datastore query to fetch keys along with other properties of a kind

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I use the node query below to fetch all properties of the kind - 'venue'

```
app.get("/api/venues/", (req, res, next) => {
    const query = datastore
    .createQuery('venue');

    query.run().then((venuesList) => {
    /*do something*/
  })
})
```

However, i don't get back the keys if i run the above get query in node.
Also documentation say we can get all the keys of a kind in datastore using query like below -

```
const query = datastore
  .createQuery()
  .select('__key__')
  .limit(1);
```

But how can i associate these two to get all the properties including keys for a given kind in the query?

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot of research and came up with the below solution for my question and it is working.

The get request through node will fetch all the entities from datastore and all these entities along with their keys would be visible on the node interface. However, the keys of the entities would not be visible on the UI(Angular, which i am using) eventough we pass on the same json(with entities) to the UI.

So i made a modification on my json obtained from datastore. I extracted the keys of entities seperately and created a new attribute within the same json and passed on this modified json to the UI. So now, i was able to access the keys of entities through an alias attribute which i created at node. Check the modified code below -

```
app.get("/api/venues/", (req, res, next) => {
    const query = datastore
    .createQuery('venue');

    query.run().then(([venuesList]) => {
    venuesList.forEach(venue => { venue['venueKey'] = venue[datastore.KEY] });
    //venuesList.forEach(venue => console.log(venue));
    res.status(200).json(
      {
        message: "Request was processed successfully!",
        venues: venuesList
      }
    );
  })
})
```